# how to configure tomcat to handle rhtml pages using jruby?

Tags: ruby, tomcat, jruby, erb, rhtml

How can I configure tomcat to handle .rhtml pages with jruby?

I guess I should mess around with the web.xml file, but I don't know how...

(ideally, without rails, just the necessary stuff to use erb for rendering rhtml pages...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be simpler ways, but here are a few ideas :-

1. Use [JRuby-Rack](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby-rack/pages/Home) in combination with one of the more lightweight Rack-compatible Ruby web frameworks like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). [Warbler](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/) might be useful in wrapping up the application into a `.war` file for simple deployment to Tomcat.
2. If you are using Apache in front of Tomcat, you could [use a Ruby CGI script](http://dekstop.de/weblog/2006/01/rhtml_on_osx_with_apache_and_erb/) to interpolate the `.rhtml` files.
3. If the `.rhtml` files can be interpolated before being deployed (i.e. they do not rely on variables only available at run-time), you could use a framework like [Webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org/) and then just serve them as static files.

Comment: hey, floehopper, thanks for your reply... I did the same a couple of days agos with gsp (groovy server pages) and I just had to add a couple of entries to tomcat's web.xml file... I asume there is solution as easy as that for jruby... right? I'll try what you told me and then I'll tell, thanks...

Comment: There may be a solution as easy as that, but I haven't seen it.